# Failed to transform artifact com.twilio:video-android

Tags: android, gradle, twilio

After upgrading my Gradle plugin from the current version 3.5.3 to version 3.6.0 and Gradle to version 5.6.4, my project fails to build.

I get this error "`Failed to transform artifact (com.twilio:video-android:5.1.0)`"

how to fix this? When I revert my gradle version, it starts to build again, though some other things starts to annoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fixed a bug where users of VideoView can not compile the SDK when
>   building with Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0

You should use the latest version instead of the old.

```
implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:5.1.2'
```

Read [SDK not compiling on AGP 3.6.0](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/issues/479).